# ¿Cómo encontrar la primera letra y la primera vocal en una cadena?

Tags: java

Necesito crear  y llenar un EditText que obtenga el contenido de otro EditText, pero solo la primera letra y la primera vocal.

Por ejemplo:

`EditText : FRANK  Output : FA`

De momento llevo esto:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText Result;
    private EditText MyName;
    private EditText showResult;
    private String MyVowel;
    private String cadena, PartOne;
    private int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
        MyName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameInput);
        getInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getInfoButton);
        getInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



    @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputText = myName.getText().toString();
                String partOne= inputText.substring(0,1);


        for(int i=0;i <inputText.length();i++){
                    if((inputText.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'e')  ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                            (inputText.charAt(i) == 'u')) {

                        System.out.println(cadena);

                    }
                }
        showResult.setText(PartOne);
    }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Podes especificar que no funciona?? parece q nunca estas agarrando la primera vocal (mas alla que si la palabra empieza con vocal, va a andar todo muy mal)

Comment: @Error404: Forumlé una pregunta en meta para llamar la atención: [¿Qué hacer con esta pregunta en inglés, que fue traducida por alguién que no es OP?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123/qu%C3%A9-hacer-con-esta-pregunta-en-ingl%C3%A9s-que-fue-traducida-por-algui%C3%A9n-que-no-es)

Comment: @Diana Te recomiendo registrar tu usuario y volver a realizar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto. A mi me funciona.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView result;
        private EditText myName;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResult);
            myName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameInput);
            Button getInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getInfoButton);
            getInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String inputText = myName.getText().toString();
                    String cadena= inputText.substring(0,1);

                    boolean vocal = false;
                    int i = 0;
                    while(i < inputText.length() & !vocal){
                        if((inputText.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
                                (inputText.charAt(i) == 'e')  ||
                                (inputText.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
                                (inputText.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                                (inputText.charAt(i) == 'u')) {

                            cadena = cadena+inputText.charAt(i);
                            vocal = true;

                        }
                      i++;
                    }
                    result.setText(cadena);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```